# flash cursor - ready .fla to make additional same movieclip playing while not moved (+.fla attached)

Tags: flash, actionscript, cursor, mouse

I have purchased a flash cursor (.fla) with nice sparkling effects while a cursor is being moved. I would like to make similar/same sparkles playing around a cursor ALSO while a mouse is not being moved. but only stackoverflow.com has the experience in flash, I do lack of it. i use adobe flash cs5 and tried to find a solution for a hell of hours, but unsucessfully. zipped cursor file .fla can be downloaded here:

http://grazipana.webs.com/fla.rar

could you please look at actionscript of layers - how can I edit them to make the same/similar movieclip playing around mouse while a cursor is not being moved?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, how exactly do you want the sparkles to play? Should they be everywhere, or just at the top? You can either manipulate the actionsript to create random patterns, or you could animate one movieclip of a sparkle effect and replicate where necessary?

Comment: Hi Peter, It would be amazing to have them playing similarly as they are happening when a mouse is being moved, You see it better in .fla, but i would say it is random patterns. please keep this topic updated, thanks. if it is possible, you might send it to ibelieveinbutterflies@gmail.com, i will post it here later

Comment: Hey Dania,

A the moment I am really stuck into an assignment, although the problem doesn't seem to be to difficult to sort out. You main task is to get the stage to spawn the "Star object" movieclip randomly and in many places. All the rotation work is done inside the "Star object" so the effect will be the same should you spawn it randomly on stage.

Kind Regards,
Peter

Comment: thanks Pete for advice, but could you please offer the steps or codes necessary to spawn the movieclip in many places? i am sure you are more experienced than me, so I have no idea how to do this, do i need to copy movieclip?